# ExpressJS - Using both parameter based route and absolute route

Tags: node.js, express, url-routing

I have the following routes defined.

Parameter based route

```
app.get('/:id',function(req,res){
   //Use the req.params.id
});
```

Absolute route

```
app.get('/login', function(req,res){
   //Render login page
});
```

The GET requests to the /login route is never reached as express matches it to the first route(/:id). How do i co-exist both params based and absolute routes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of the routes matters.

As you have a more general route coming first, it gets called instead of your less general route (the login).

You should place the login route above the id route

```
app.get('/login', function(req,res){
   //Render login page
});

app.get('/:id',function(req,res){
   //Use the req.params.id
});
```

Comment: I've organized the routes into different files- auth.js, status.js etc. Is there a way to set priority for the same?

Comment: It depends on how you call the routes. It's a good idea to give them different prefixes, like `/account/login` and `/user/:id` then you won't have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

[Vsevolod's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32970120/3813210) is the simplest and most efficient way to solve the problem. However, for the sake of reference, there is also another way you could do it:

```
app.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.params.id === "login") {
        return next(); // skip to the next route handler
    }

   // response code here
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res){
   // response code here
});
```